# Remove Duplicates from a list XSLT 1.0 based on element value

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need help with writing a function in xslt 1.0 that I can pass a list and it'll return the list with duplicates removed. It needs to be a template that I can easily clone or modify for other lists since there are several lists that I want to be able to run this.

Here is one example:

Input list:

```
 <Diagnoses>
      <Code>444.4</Code>
      <Code>959.99</Code>
      <Code>524</Code>
      <Code>444.4</Code>
    </Diagnoses>
```

Desired Output, after the duplicate code value 444.4 is removed:

```
 <Diagnoses>
    <Code>444.4</Code>
    <Code>959.99</Code>
    <Code>524</Code>
 </Diagnoses>
```

Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math" 
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
xmlns:data="http://example.com/data" version="1.0" 
extension-element-prefixes="math exsl" 
exclude-result-prefixes="math exsl data">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />






<xsl:variable name="DiagnosesList" select="Diagnoses"/>

<Diagnoses>
   <xsl:call-template name="DedupeLists">
      <xsl:with-param name="Input" select = "exsl:node-set($DiagnosesList)" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</Diagnoses>


<xsl:template name="DedupeLists">
    <xsl:param name = "Input" />

    <xsl:for-each select="$Input/*">
     <xsl:if test="Code[not(preceding::Code)]">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: See: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. Or, if your processor supports it: http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html -- P.S. In your example, $DiagnosesList is already a node-set.

Comment: One more thing: Muechian grouping (which is the **efficient** method to group/de-dupe nodes) requires you to pre-define a key for these nodes. This key cannot be reused for other nodes, so your expectation to have a generic named template for this is unrealistic, unless you are willing to settle for less efficient methods (such as having each node check all of its preceding siblings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@lingamurthy,

Just

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Code[. = preceding-sibling::Code]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you. This does it too.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Code[not(. = preceding-sibling::Code)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Code"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```